# Replace items in a string with values from an array

Tags: php

I have a string of values separated by semicolon.

```
$str = 'value 12; another value; yet one more one; val5';
```

I also have an array where the keys correspond to the values in the string above.

How do I replace the values in the string with the values from the array? Now, I think I can explode the string by semi-colon and trim the space

```
$arr = array_map('trim', explode(';', $str));
```

Do I need to run the array through a loop and use the values as keys and then implode it back? Is there a faster way?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve here? can I get an example of the array? what is it like? you have an array full of special characters and you just want to replace those chracters with something when you encounter them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using `str_ireplace` can help you the most and code should look like below.

```
$str = 'value 12; another value; yet one more one; val5';
$assocArray = [
                  "value 12" => "Value goes here",
                  "another value" => "values_goes", 
                  "yet one more one" => "more value", 
                  "val5" => "value 5"
              ];
// if you need strict comparison with keys then go with str_replace
$newString = str_ireplace(array_keys($assocArray), $assocArray, $str);
```

Comment: This approach can fail when one value is a substring of another value.

Answer (score 0):

[str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) will accept arrays of tokens and values to replace them. Thus

```
<?php

$str = 'value 12; another value; yet one more one; val5';
$src = ["value 12", "another value", "yet one more one", "val5"];
$tgt = ["red","green","blue","violet"];

$res = str_replace($src, $tgt, $str);
echo $res;    // red; green; blue; violet
```

See: https://3v4l.org/kN8VW

Comment: This approach can fail when one value is a substring of another value.